# How to keep functions short when dealing with closures in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, code-readability

Given the following code, which implements a closure:

```
function scopeDef(){

  var privateField_1 = 1;
  .
  .
  .
  var privateField_8 = 8;

  return function someFunction() {
         /* Implementation takes 10 lines, and uses the private fields */
  }

}
```

I want to maintain code readability and conventions, by keeping every function in the code shorter then lets say 10 code lines.

I need to simply move the implementation of `someFunction()` outside of `scopeDef()` , and still be able to access the private fields from within `someFunction()`.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Any reason you can't declare someFunction outside of the scopeDef and then give it some parameters? If the privateFields are by value and not reference then I think it would work.

Comment: The real question should be: Do you really need to close over 8 variables for a 10-line function? It would help if you could post your full, actual code so that we can see which approaches will work and which don't apply to your situation.

Comment: @minorcase, I would like to assign the invocation of  `defScope` into a variable, and then invoke the variable itself whenever I'd like, while maintaining the variables, and keep them private.

I don't see how could I achieve this if I create `someFunction(...privateVariables..)` outside of `scopeDef().

Comment: @Bergi I understand your meaning, but I'm more interested if doing such thing is possible, rather then knowing if it's the right thing for my code, so I'd rather not to post my code.

I definitely understand that it might be stupid to achieve this, because it won't lead to a serious reduction in the function length in the general case, and yet I'd like to know whether is it possible to achieve that.

Comment: @GoldenSpecOps No, I'm not saying that it might be the wrong thing, I'm saying that there is no generic solution (and there exist cases of closures where it is indeed impossible). Show us your code, and we can tell you what is possible in your case (regardless whether it's useful or not).

Comment: A closure is meant to take something that is a variable of a higher scope and restrict its scope or capture its value at an instance in time (in my understanding). I'm with @bergi, your goals don't seem to jive with this technique.

The fact of the matter is if you want to have a closure using your private variables, you need to get their values inside that function at some point. Decide when that is and how you want to do it. They are still private variables, you should use something like a getter or a setter in order to access them at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind` to set the context of the function. You can define `someFunction()` outside of the context of the closure, and then within the closure return `someFunction.bind(this)` instead.

```
function publicMethod() { /* ... */ }

function closure() {
  /* ... */

  return publicMethod.bind(this)
}
```

for example

```
function logA() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

function closure() {
  this.a = 'context';
  return logA.bind(this);
}
```